# Getting an error while trying to run my project on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This my java code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

and this xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.khanousse.lite.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="298dp"
    android:layout_height="182dp"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't why i get this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   >java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: is this your only code ? id not plese post your whole code .I guess there is a problem in your array

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem earlier days, i resolved it by just

1. Clean your project `build>clean`
2. Rebuild project `build>rebuild`